# How can I add input field and select dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I have an input fields and a select option with MySQL values. How can I add dynamically more input fields and select with MySQL values? I'm trying to solve this, but the result is terrible:

[image]

I want to use this to update My database, and I can update multiple datas with it, but the Remove previous fields button doesn't working and there is +1 Add more button at the end. How can I solve this problem? I'm trying with the append method, but it doesn't working with MySQL datas.

### index.php

```
<div class="form-group add-field">
  <div class="partner">    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select name="partnerSelect[]" id="partnerSelect" class="form-control">
          <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
          <?php                                       
            while($row = $partnerResult -> fetch_array()) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['partner_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['partner'];?></option>
          <?php
            }
          ?>
          </select>  
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter description" name="description[]" id="description" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning add-more"><span>+ Add More</span></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var data_fo = $('.add-field').html();
    var sd = '<div class="btn btn-danger remove-add-more">Remove</div>';
    var data_combine = data_fo.concat(sd);
    var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".partner"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add-more"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append(data_combine); //add input box
        //$(wrapper).append('<div class="remove-add-more">Remove</div>')
      }
      // console.log(data_fo);
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove-add-more", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).prev('.partner').remove();
        //$(".add-more").prev('.user').remove(); It's remove all the buttons and inputs
        $(this).remove();
        x--;
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: you can use jQuery Repeater for clone field `http://briandetering.net/repeater`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, just a couple of things were a little off. I kept your code the same format but cleaned it up a little. Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var data_fo = $('.partner').html();
    var sd = '<div class="btn btn-danger remove-add-more">Remove</div>';
    var max_fields = 5; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".partners"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add-more"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        var partnerClone = $('.partner').first().clone();
        $(sd).appendTo(partnerClone);
        $(wrapper).append(partnerClone);
      }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove-add-more", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('.partner').remove();
        $(this).remove();
        x--;
    });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group add-field">
  <div class="partners">  
    <div class="partner">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select name="partnerSelect[]" id="partnerSelect" class="form-control">
            <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
            <?php                                       
              while($row = $partnerResult -> fetch_array()) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['partner_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['partner'];?></option>
            <?php
              }
            ?>
            </select>  
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter description" name="description[]" id="description" class="form-control" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn btn-warning add-more"><span>+ Add More</span></div>
</div>
```

I put it in a snippet so that you can run it here. But you can go back and put the Jquery in a script tag like you had before

Answer (score 0):

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#AddData").html(AddTr())

function AddTr(){
var html="<tr id="+($('tr').length)+"><td align=\"center\">"+($('tr').length)+"</td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"narration_"+($('tr').length)+"\" class=\"form-control sannarration valid\" ></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"txtremarksan_"+($('tr').length)+"\" class=\"form-control sannarration valid\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"DocSub_"+($('tr').length)+"\" class=\"form-control sannarration valid\" ></td><td align=\"center\"><a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"onlyIcon EditsancationIcon\" onclick=\"Editsanctioncondtion(this);\" title=\"Edit\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil fa-2x\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a> <a href=\"javascript:;\" class=\"onlyIcon deleteIcon text-danger\" title=\"Delete\" onclick=\"Delete(this,event)\";\"><i class=\"fa fa-times fa-2x\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></td></tr>"
return html;
}

$('#addrow').on('click',function(){
$("table tbody").append(AddTr());
})

$('#Submit').on('click',function(){
NodeId=[];
TblHead=[];
$('th').each(function(){
TblHead.push($(this).text())
})

for(var i=1;i<=parseInt($('tr').length-1);i++)
{
Obj={};
var index=0;
$('tr[id="'+i+'"] td').each(function(){
debugger
Obj[TblHead[index]]=$("#"+$(this).children(':first').attr('id')).val();
index++;
})
NodeId.push(Obj)
}
console.log(NodeId)
alert(JSON.stringify(NodeId))
})

})
function Delete(ele,event){
if(($('tr').length-1)>1)
{
debugger;
     $(ele).closest("tr").remove();
  reset(parseInt(event.currentTarget.previousSibling.parentNode.parentNode.id)) 
    }
 }
function reset (Getid)
{
debugger;
var count=Getid;
$('tr').each(function(){
if($(this)[0].id>=parseInt(Getid+1))
{
$(this).attr('id',count);
$(this).children('td:first').text(count)
$(this).children('td:first').next('td').children('input').attr('id','narration_'+count+'')
$(this).children('td:first').next('td').next('td').children('input').attr('id','txtremarksan_'+count+'')
$(this).children('td:first').next('td').next('td').next('td').children('input').attr('id','DocSub_'+count+'')
count++;
}
})
} 
            
        </script>

<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="ASSETS/BT-CP/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ASSETS/CSS/costum.css">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="ASSETS/BT-CP/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
        
    </head>
    
    <body>

      <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" border="1" id="tblsanctioncondtion" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

                                                    <thead>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th align="center" scope="col">Sr.No</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Narration</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Remark</th>
                                                            <th scope="col">Documents Submittion Date</th>
                                                            <th align="center" scope="col">Action</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody id="AddData">
             
             </tbody>
                                                </table>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right" id="addrow" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right" id="Submit" style="margin-bottom:10px;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Submit</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```